# boolean modifier fills up the intersection area

Tags: modifiers

I want to create a cut in a cube so as to create a hollow pool of water in the middle of the cube. However, when I apply the boolean modifier and remove the object used to cut into the cube, I see no actual difference. The cube is still completely solid. Only in edit mode can I see that a boolean operation has been performed, but unfortunately no hollow area is created. I hope someone can tell me what the issue is here. [image]

[image]

Comment: could you please share your file with the 2 objects, before applying the modifier?

Comment: Are you sure you used the right boolean operation ? If I understand it well enough, you'd want to use the "Difference" operation for your project. Is that what you used ?

Comment: I did use difference. Let me try to share the file

Comment: I think the blend file should be there now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the topology of the small cube, it is made of separated faces, so the *Boolean* operation can't work properly. To solve this, you need to go in *Edit* mode, select all, and <kbd>W</kbd> > *Remove Doubles*, so that it joins all the faces together and make a real cube. Then your *Boolean* will work properly.

Answer (score 1):

If you delete the top face, there is a hole. Perhaps delete the top face then select the vertices to make polygons around it and hit **f** to make a face? Does that make sense?
[image: Result of deleting top face.]
[image: Selecting vertices]
[image: Make a face]